# Can HTML5 getUserMedia access usb key files?

Tags: html

HTML5 getUserMedia can access the camera, but can it be used to access USB drive? Can I access USB drive files in a webapp?

Answer (score 0):

The [W3C spec](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/getusermedia.html) for getUserMedia defines the local devices accessible as

> "local devices (video cameras, microphones, Web cams)".

So no, usb hard drives are not part of this API.

You might want to check out the relatively new File API (HTML5) : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications